# schedule execution by testNG in Eclipse

Tags: selenium

I want my selenium(java) test scripts to be scheduled for execution every night 11.00PM.
How can I do this in Eclipse .I am using TestNG to run my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a simple tool called [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to achieve what you are trying to do. It is an excellent solution to running scheduled tasks such as running selenium test scripts.

Comment: Thanks Hari.
Can u please explain more . As I have my all testcases in a xml file.
which I execute with testNG engine in Eclipse.So how to start my execution every noght

Comment: Download the jenkins war file your respective environment and then start it by executing the war file - java -jar jenkins.war . Then you will have to configure a new job in jenkins to start executing your testcases.

Comment: As I have my all testcases in a xml file. which I execute with testNG engine in Eclipse.So how to start my execution every night at 11.00PM

Comment: How exactly do you run now? Are you using testng plugin for eclipse or running the testng xml file?

Comment: @A.J Though it is a late response.....But now I need it .I am using testng.xml file to execute my testscripts in eclipse(testNG framework)